# Serializing Jersey exceptions from filter throws error

Tags: java, json, jersey, cxf

I currently have a RESTful webservice running Jersey.  I recently added a filter that does some auth stuff, and it works in the happy-path case.  However, when I need to throw an error from within this filter, instead of serializing the exception into a pretty json string it, it throws a 500 with the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message
body writer for Java class myclass, and Java type class myclass, and MIME media type
application/octet-stream was not found
```

The thing is, I don't want to write anything to application/octet-stream.  My service only uses `application/json`.  This is not a problem in my actual `Resource` classes, where I can specify the`@Produces` annotation.  Error responses thrown from the body of a resource will serialize properly.

My question, then, is: How do I control what MIME type is used for exceptions thrown while filtering?

Comment: Have you added a `servlet filter` or a `jersey filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an exceptionmapper to handle the exceptions and turn them in to JSON.  Something like:

```
@Provider
public class UnexpectedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(final Exception exception)
  {
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                                      .entity(jsonError(exception))
                                      .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return builder.build();
  }

  private String jsonError(final Exception exception)
  {
    return "{\"error\":\"" + exception.getMessage() + "\"}";
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I had tried the exceptionmapper route, and I couldn't get it work.  However, your answer did have the solution contained in it.  The problem I was having was that any exception I threw from within the filtering step was getting turned into a different exception by CXF (the one about the unknown writer for octet-stream).  It turns out that all I needed to do was to explicitly define the type during the response building step (which you do here with the .type() call).  I had never run into this before because all of my other exceptions were thrown from places where @Produces was available.